# Have to remove duplicate entry from XML file on basis of User ID, using DOM parser in Java

Tags: java, xml, parsing, dom, duplicates

I am using DOM parser to parse xml file to get multiple Tab separated txt file to get CVS file as an output. I am able to get the output file as required in proper format with limited node elements to dispatch.
What I want is I need to check if the any of the row is having similar data, that I need to merge and make it one row only. The xml is containing data of multiple pages, where the xml contain so many similar pages in it. so remove the duplicate one.

```
public class XMLParsingToTextFile {

    private static String FILENAME = "";

    public static void main(String[] args){

        BufferedWriter bw = null;
        FileWriter fw = null;
        try {
            FILENAME = args[1];

            fw = new FileWriter(FILENAME);
            bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);

            SimpleDateFormat fromUser = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
            SimpleDateFormat changeDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
            Date now = new Date();
            String todayDate = changeDateFormat.format(now);

            File inputFile = new File(args[0]);

            DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = dBuilder.parse(inputFile);
            doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

            System.out.println("Root element :"+ doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());

            NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("KNOBJECT");
            for (int temp = 0; temp < nList.getLength(); temp++) {
                Node nNode = nList.item(temp);
                if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                    Element eElement = (Element) nNode;
                    String type = null;
                    String id = null;
                    String problem = null;
                    String steps = null;
                    String title = null;
                    String action = null;
                    String cause = null;
                    String toxonomyPath = null;
                    String shortSolution = null;
                    String solution = null;
                    String errorMessage = null;
                    String author = null;
                    String renewDate = null;
                    String publishWorkflow = "Knowledge - Instant Publish";
                    String retireWorkflow = "Knowledge - Instant Retire";
                    String active = "True";
                    String value = null;
                    String label = null;

                    String startHTML = "<table cellpadding=\"5\" cellspacing=\"0\" border=\"0\" class=\"solutionTable\">";
                    String errorHTML = "<tr><td class=\"sectionLabel\">Error Message:</td><td class=\"sectionContent\">ERROR_MESSAGE</td></tr>";
                    String causeHTML = "<tr><td class=\"sectionLabel\">Cause:</td><td class=\"sectionContent\">CAUSE</td></tr>";
                    String solutHTML = "<tr><td class=\"sectionLabel\">Solution:</td><td class=\"sectionContent\">SOLUTION</td></tr>";
                    String detlHTML  = "<tr><td class=\"sectionLabel\">Details:</td><td class=\"sectionContent\">Steps</td></tr>";
                    String sytmHTML  = "<tr><td class=\"sectionLabel\">Symptoms:</td><td class=\"sectionContent\">ALTERNATE_SYMPTOM<br/></td></tr>";
                    String endHTML   = "</table>";


                    type = getContentText(eElement,"TYPE",0);
                    id = getContentText(eElement,"ID",0);
                    renewDate = getContentText(eElement,"RENEWDATE",0);
                    renewDate = changeDateFormat.format(fromUser.parse(renewDate));
                    title = getContentText(eElement,"Title",0);
                    problem = getContentText(eElement,"Problem",0);
                    steps = getContentText(eElement,"Steps",0);
                    cause = getContentText(eElement,"CAUSE",0);
                    toxonomyPath = getContentText(eElement,"TAXONOMY_PATH",0);
                    shortSolution = getContentText(eElement,"SHORT_SOLUTION",0);
                    solution = getContentText(eElement,"SOLUTION",0);
                    errorMessage = getContentText(eElement,"ERROR_MESSAGE",0);
                    author = getContentText(eElement,"Author",0);
                    kbCategory = toxonomyPath.split("\\|")[1];
                    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
                    sb.append(startHTML);
                    if(errorMessage != null && errorMessage.trim().length() > 0 ){
                        sb.append(errorHTML.replaceAll("ERROR_MESSAGE", errorMessage).trim());
                    }
                    if(cause != null && cause.trim().length() > 0 ){
                        sb.append(causeHTML.replaceAll("CAUSE", cause).trim());
                    }
                    if(solution != null && solution.trim().length() > 0 ){
                        sb.append(solutHTML.replaceAll("SOLUTION", solution).trim());
                    }
                    if(steps != null && steps.trim().length() > 0 ){
                        sb.append(detlHTML.replaceAll("Steps", steps).trim());
                    }
                    sb.append(endHTML);

                    String isActive = null;
                        if (todayDate.compareTo(renewDate)>0 ){
                            isActive = "N";
                    }
                        else{
                            isActive = "Y";
                    }

                    String  outputCSVFile = contString(id,title,renewDate,sb.toString(),author,toxonomyPath.split("\\|")[0],toxonomyPath.split("\\|")[1],shortSolution,isActive);
                    bw.write(outputCSVFile+"\n");
                }
            bw.close();
            System.out.println("Process complete");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static String getContentText(Element eElement,String tagName,int index){
        try{
            String contentTxt = eElement.getElementsByTagName(tagName).item(index).getTextContent().toString().trim();
            return contentTxt;
        } catch (Exception e){
            return null;
        }
    }

    public static String contString(String ID, String title, String valid_to,String  htmlFormate, String author,String kb_knowledge_base,
                String kb_category,String description, String active){

        return ID +'\t'+ title+'\t'+valid_to+'\t'+htmlFormate+'\t'+author+'\t'+kb_knowledge_base+'\t'+kb_category+'\t'+description+'\t'+active;
    }
```

}

I need to check the second output file, where any row is repeating, that I need to merge on basis of the String id.

How can I remove the duplicate in output file?

sharing you the xml file below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RESULTS Server="http://www.knowledgepak.com/ssxml/resultsxml.asp" STL-NAME="results" STL-VERSION="1.00">
  <KNOBJECT>
    <Problem><![CDATA[Error: Receive the file 'iTunes Library' cannot be read error in Mac OS X Lion.]]></Problem>
    <Steps><![CDATA[<smsolution><p>Mac OS X Lion is a Mac operating system that provides the iTunes</smsolution>]]></Steps>
    <Title><![CDATA[Error: Receive the file 'iTunes Library' cannot be read error in Mac OS X Lion.]]></Title>
    <CAUSE><![CDATA[<smsolution><p>The error occurs because the updated version of the iTunes is not installed.</p></smsolution>]]></CAUSE>
    <TAXONOMY_PATH><![CDATA[Infrastructure - Desktop | Telecom//DH Apple Mac//DH iTunes 10//DH Troubleshooting]]></TAXONOMY_PATH>
    <ALTERNATE_SYMPTOM><![CDATA[Receive an error while opening iTunes in Mac OS X Lion.]]></ALTERNATE_SYMPTOM>
    <SHORT_SOLUTION><![CDATA[Install an updated version of iTunes.]]></SHORT_SOLUTION>
    <TYPE><![CDATA[error solution]]></TYPE>
    <SOLUTION><![CDATA[<smsolution><p>From 'Apple' menu, click 'Software Update'. Click 'Show Details' button. Select 'iTunes' check box. Click 'Install' button.</p></smsolution>]]></SOLUTION>
    <ID><![CDATA[133954940]]></ID>
    <ERROR_MESSAGE><![CDATA[<SMSOLUTION>The file 'iTunes Library' cannot be read because it was created by a newer version of iTunes.]]></ERROR_MESSAGE>
    <Author><![CDATA[seanlinehan]]></Author>
    <RENEWDATE><![CDATA[20170415]]></RENEWDATE>
  </KNOBJECT>
  <KNOBJECT>
    <Problem><![CDATA[Error: Receive iPod Service could not be installed error in iTunes 10.]]></Problem>
    <Steps><![CDATA[<smsolution><p>iTunes 10 is a media player application, used for playing and managing audio </smsolution>]]></Steps>
    <Title><![CDATA[Error: Receive iPod Service could not be installed error in iTunes 10.]]></Title>
    <CAUSE><![CDATA[<smsolution><p>The problem occurs if the iPod service is not deleted even after it is marked for deletion.</p></smsolution>]]></CAUSE>
    <TAXONOMY_PATH><![CDATA[Infrastructure - Desktop | Telecom//DH Apple Mac//DH iTunes 10//DH Troubleshooting]]></TAXONOMY_PATH>
    <SHORT_SOLUTION><![CDATA[Restart computer without canceling iTunes installation.]]></SHORT_SOLUTION>
    <TYPE><![CDATA[error solution]]></TYPE>
    <SOLUTION><![CDATA[<smsolution><p>Right-click 'Computer' and click 'Manage'. Expand 'Services and Applications\Services'.</p></smsolution>]]></SOLUTION>
    <ID><![CDATA[134854936]]></ID>
    <ERROR_MESSAGE><![CDATA[<SMSOLUTION>Service 'iPod Service' (iPod Service) could not be installed.]]></ERROR_MESSAGE>
    <Author><![CDATA[seanlinehan]]></Author>
    <RENEWDATE><![CDATA[20170415]]></RENEWDATE>
  </KNOBJECT>
  <KNOBJECT>
    <Problem><![CDATA[Error: Receive error 306 or 10054 in iTunes 10.]]></Problem>
    <Steps><![CDATA[<smsolution><p>iTunes 10 is a media player application, used for playing and managing audio and video files.</smsolution>]]></Steps>
    <Title><![CDATA[Error: Receive error 306 or 10054 in iTunes 10.]]></Title>
    <CAUSE><![CDATA[<smsolution><p>The problem may occur if there is an issue with the 'NetworkInterfaces.plist' file.</p></smsolution>]]></CAUSE>
    <TAXONOMY_PATH><![CDATA[Infrastructure - Desktop | Telecom//DH Apple Mac//DH iTunes 10//DH Troubleshooting]]></TAXONOMY_PATH>
    <SHORT_SOLUTION><![CDATA[Rebuild network information.]]></SHORT_SOLUTION>
    <SOLUTION><![CDATA[<smsolution><p>In 'Finder', from 'Go' menu, click 'Go to Folder'.</p></smsolution>]]></SOLUTION>
    <ID><![CDATA[133954940]]></ID>
    <ERROR_MESSAGE><![CDATA[<SMSOLUTION>Error 306 or error 10054.]]></ERROR_MESSAGE>
    <Author><![CDATA[seanlinehan]]></Author>
    <RENEWDATE><![CDATA[20170415]]></RENEWDATE>
  </KNOBJECT>
  <KNOBJECT>
    <Problem><![CDATA[Error: Receive iPodService Module (32-bit) error in iTunes 10.]]></Problem>
    <Steps><![CDATA[<smsolution><p>iTunes 10 is a media player application, used for playing and managing audio and video files.</smsolution>]]></Steps>
    <Title><![CDATA[Error: Receive iPodService Module (32-bit) error in iTunes 10.]]></Title>
    <CAUSE><![CDATA[<smsolution><p>The problem may occur if there is an issue with the iTunes 10 installation.</p></smsolution>]]></CAUSE>
    <TAXONOMY_PATH><![CDATA[Infrastructure - Desktop | Telecom//DH Apple Mac//DH iTunes 10//DH Troubleshooting]]></TAXONOMY_PATH>
    <SHORT_SOLUTION><![CDATA[Revert from iTunes 10 to iTunes 9.2.1 and copy iPod folder.]]></SHORT_SOLUTION>
    <TYPE><![CDATA[error solution]]></TYPE>
    <SOLUTION><![CDATA[<smsolution><p>Revert from&nbsp;iTunes 10 to iTunes 9.2.1.</p></smsolution>]]></SOLUTION>
    <ID><![CDATA[160415135027230]]></ID>
    <ERROR_MESSAGE><![CDATA[<SMSOLUTION>iPodService Module (32-bit) has encountered a problem and needs to close.]]></ERROR_MESSAGE>
    <Author><![CDATA[seanlinehan]]></Author>
    <RENEWDATE><![CDATA[20170415]]></RENEWDATE>
  </KNOBJECT>
</RESULTS>
```

Comment: Looking at your XML example data, you have <ID> element. You can use ID value if already processed to filter out messages having similar IDs. Hope it would help!

Comment: @fabfas I have thousands -lacs of data available in a xml file. Ss need to know how I can handle ID file which is having similar values in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added a set variable

```
Set<String> strSet=new HashSet<>();
```

and before writing I am passing the complete data in the set as,
In place of

```
bw.write(outputCSVFile+"\n");
```

Writing

```
strSet.add(outputCSVFile);
```

and before closing the bufferedWriter, a for loop is added to check weather the values are repeating in a set or not.
i.e.,

```
for(String finalKnowledgeBase:strSet)
        {
            bw.write(outputCSVFile+ "\n");
        }
bw.close();
```

The output file will remove all the duplicate entry in that string.

Answer (score 0):

In `DOM`, no events triggered while parsing. The entire XML is parsed and a DOM tree is generated and returned.

In your case when XML file size is big, the choice would be SAX to parse XML. In `SAX`, events are triggered when the XML is being parsed. When the parser is parsing the XML, and encounters a tag starting (e.g. `<ID>`), then it triggers the tag started event. Similarly when the end of the tag is met while parsing (e.g. `</ID>`), it triggers tag ended. Using SAX parser, you need to handle events and decide about the data returned with each event.

You can keep saving the state of processed messages (i.e. ID of processed messages), on subsequent events just compare the ID whether it has been processed or not. If already processed, you can ignore that XML element.

Comment: I am handling the duplicate row using set in java program. It will help me to remove all the duplicate row which contain same value in it.